# Parfor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I'm trying to run this loop as a parfor-loop:

```
correlations = zeros(1,N);   
parfor i = 1:(size(timestamps,1)-1)
    j = i+1;
    dts = timestamps(j) - timestamps(i);
    while (dts < T) && (j <= size(timestamps,1))
        if dts == 0 && detectors(i) ~= detectors(j)
            correlations(1) = correlations(1) + 2;
        elseif detectors(i) ~= detectors(j)
            dts = floor(dts/binning)+1;
            correlations(dts) = correlations(dts) + 1;
        end
        j = j + 1;
        if j <= size(timestamps,1)
            dts = timestamps(j) - timestamps(i);
        end
    end
end
```

Matlab gives me the following error:

```
Error: File: correlate_xcorr.m Line: 18 Column: 17
The variable correlations in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".
```

Line 18 is the following:

```
correlations(1) = correlations(1) + 2;
```

I can not understand why this shouldn'n be possible. The final value of correlations doesn't depend on the order in which the loop is executed, but only dts and detectors. I found similar examples in the documentation which work fine.

Why can't Matlab execute this code and how can I fix it?

Comment: fixing the German text would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry I got a little confused for a second.

Comment: I don't mind, but staying with the English would be better :)

Comment: Watch out, that's a race condition! All your parallel process are trying to access and edit that same element correlations(1) so if two of them read it at the same time and both try update it by adding 1 it will only get 1 added instead of 2. This will produce the wrong answer even if there are no errors. Maybe matlab recognizes this and is trying to stop you? You might have to block the variable with an if statement to make sure none of the other processes can read it until it has been written to?

Comment: unless you mean correlation(**i**) and not **1** ?

Comment: No correlation(1) is correct. If you what you say is true than why can Matlab run this code:
s = 0;
parfor i = 1:100
    s = s+i;
end

Comment: Well like I said, even if it doesn't error, you're still leaving yourself open to getting the wrong answer because that is a race condition. Try it to 1000000

Comment: @Dan: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/getting-started-with-parfor.html#brdqn6p-1

Comment: @Stein: read about how `parfor` classifies variables into 5 types: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html

Comment: @Amro I see. Those mathworks guys, they're pretty smart.

Comment: The way I see it correlation is used as a reduction variable and only this way in the loop. This is why a can not understand why Matlab causes a Error. My program is completely independent of the order in which the loop body is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution and it seems to work. The program looks a litte different, but it has the same shape. This way Matlab is forced to think x/correlations is a reduction variable.

```
X = zeros(1,5);
parfor i= 1:1000
    a = zeros(1,5);
    dts = randi(10)-1;
    if dts == 0
        a(1) = (a(1) + 2);
    elseif dts <= 5
        a(dts) = a(dts) +1;
    end
    X = X + a;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB cannot determine that your loop is order independent because of the way you're accessing correlations(1) from multiple iterations of the PARFOR loop. It looks like this value is in some way 'special', it should work to make a 'reduction' variable, i.e. replace `correlations(1)` with `correlations_1` or something.

The next problem you'll encounter is that you are not correctly 'slicing' the remainder of `correlations`. For  MATLAB to analyse a PARFOR loop, it needs to be able to tell that each loop iteration is writing only to its 'slice' of the output variables. In practice, this means that you must index the outputs using literally the loop index.

More about PARFOR variable classification here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_of7_-1

EDIT:

If you want `correlations` to behave strictly as a reduction variable as I believe you imply in your comments, you need to give PARFOR a clue that's what you mean: in particular, you need to add to the whole variable each time you need to. In other words, something more like:

```
parfor ...
    dummyVec = zeros(1, N);
    dummyVec(elementToIncrement) = 1;
    correlations = correlations + dummyVec;
end
```

I agree this is non-obvious. See http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/11/26/magic-squares-meet-supercomputing/ for more.

Comment: Yes this would solve the problem in line 18, but it is just delayed to line 21: correlations(dts) = correlations(dts) + 1; Here the solution fails, because correlations needs to be an array here and can not be replaced with a variable.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said that you're not slicing `correlations` correctly.